# WatchOS5 - "Could not load file-transfer-result" of WCSessionFileTransfer

Tags: swift4, ios12, watchos-5

I'm trying to send 2 files to my Apple Watch app. It worked initially, but now I'm getting 2 errors printed in the console.

```
WCSession.default.transferFile(fileURL1, metadata: ["name":"first"])
WCSession.default.transferFile(fileURL2, metadata: ["name":"second")
```

**Who is printing the error - is it my the test app on the iPhone?**

**Can I transfer 2 files in sequence, or are there limitations - do I need to wait for the first transfer to complete?**

> 2018-11-18 11:05:53.010374-0500 SimpleWatchConnectivity[836:23347]
>   [WC] -[WCFileStorage enumerateFileTransferResultsWithBlock:] could not
>   load file data at path
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C07047D9-87F7-4CBD-AE79-AAE26D93A400/Library/Application
>   Support/com.apple.watchconnectivity/46CAD076-37A8-4B60-A93E-F0F21F457593/**FileTransfers/D9E589D8-E21B-4A34-9A29-8D6B53E997D5/file-transfer-result**

The documentation makes it seem like the files are enqueued, so I'm not sure as to what is causing the error:

> /** The system will enqueue the file and transfer it to the
>   counterpart app at an opportune time. The transfer of a file will
>   continue after the sending app has exited. The counterpart app will
>   receive a delegate callback on next launch if the file has
>   successfully arrived. The metadata dictionary can only accept the
>   property list types. */

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue.